# Out-GridView in PowerShell: How to change the initial size of the window?

Tags: powershell, gridview

I often work with the useful function Out-GridView in PowerShell. Sometimes I only have little data to show in the GridView but it opens in a very big window every time. Is there a possibility to change the initial size of the GridView window? A table with 3 columns and 4 rows should not be displayed in a window that is nearly fullscreen on a 1920x1080 display ...

Comment: out-gridview is actually freaking awesome for what it does. And that they ported it to work in Linux powershell, too. But certainly it leaves me wanting more... like some parameters:
-topX, -topY, -height, -width, -minheight, -minwidth
...and so on. 
or if it was part of a library module with other things, like dialogs. or even better, if it allowed selecting "cell" values for cut-and-paste, not just the whole row (or dumping the selected line to the console). Because it's fun (not fun) having ogv create a window on a 4K display...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell is a scripting language, not really a GUI language. It's possible to create GUI's with the help of tools like SAPIEN PowerShell Studio and others, by using Winforms or wpf.

In short, what you want is not possible I'm afraid, as there's no [parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849920.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for it.

Comment: Thank you, even I got no solution! ;-)

Comment: I understand your need thought, but it's just not meant for that. Have a nice day.

Comment: If you are desperate enough. . .you could definitely accomplish this with the classes available in the UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes assemblies.  I did a quick proof-of-concept and was able to easily identify and resize the grid window.  Picking a good size for it, OTOH, is more complex - vertically, you'd need to add up the heights of the filter box, the criteria dropdown, the datagrid header, the dataitem rows and the OK/Cancel buttons; horizontally, the width of the datagrid header is probably good.  And you probably don't want to exceed the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and ended up using this "workaround" that autosizes.

```
$null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll')

$words = @"
    Line 1
    This is the line after line 1
    The third line contains the number 5.
"@

#if "words" is an array, change below to ($words | out-string)

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox(($words),0, "Title")
```